# Why won't my form upload to my database? after submitting the databse is still empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I run this code it all goes fine. It gives me the message "New record inserted succesfully". The problem that I have is whenever I go to my databse to check it out. It's still empty, the information that I typed into the input boxes don't appear in my database. Just a blank database. I'm new to coding so please bear with me if I misused some words or don't quite understand my mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Sign Up Form</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SignUp.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="color:white">Username :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Username" required></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="color:white">voornaam :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Voornaam" required></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="color:white">Achternaam :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Achternaam" required></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="color:white">Wachtwoord :</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="Wachtwoord" required></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="color:white">Adres :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Adress" required></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
        <td style="color:white">Telefoon nummer :</td>
        <td>
         <select name="Telcode" required>
          <option selected hidden value="">Select Code</option>
          <option value="297">297</option>
         </select>
         <input type="phone" name="Telnummer" required>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>


    <?php
    $Voornaam = $_POST['Voornaam'];
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Achternaam = $_POST['Achternaam'];
    $Wachtwoord = $_POST['Wachtwoord'];
    $Adress = $_POST['Adress'];
    $Telcode = $_POST['Telcode'];
    $Telnummer = $_POST['Telnummer'];
    if (!empty($Voornaam) || !empty($Achternaam) || !empty($Wachtwoord) || !empty($Adress) || !empty($Telcode) || !empty($Telnummer) || !empty($Username)) 
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbUsername = "root";
        $dbPassword = "root"; 
        $dbname = "gevuldetomaat"; 



        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error)   {
         die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
                                    } else      { 

         $SELECT = "SELECT Username From klant Where Username = ? Limit 1";
         $INSERT = "INSERT INTO klant (Wachtwoord, Achternaam, Voornaam, Telnummer, Telcode, Username, Adress) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


         $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
         $stmt->bind_param("s", $Username);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->bind_result($Username);
         $stmt->store_result();
           $rnum = $stmt->num_rows; 
         if ($rnum==0) 
                    {
          $stmt->close();
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
          $stmt->bind_param("sssiiss", $Wachtwoord, $Achternaam, $Voornaam, $Telnummer, $Telcode, $Username, $Adress);
          $stmt->execute();
          echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
                    } 
         else   {
          echo "Someone already registered using this name";
                }
         $stmt->close();
         $conn->close();
                                                    }

    } 
    else    {
        echo "All fields are required";
        die();
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the logs? What does the server return on POST (look in developer tools)? Add some PHP debugging statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you do run into that fork where the `INSERT` SQL runs, but you print the success message without checking whether it indeed was successfully inserted or not

After each `mysqli_stmt::execute()`, you should consider checking the `mysqli_stmt::$errno` variable to see if there was an error or not (`$errno` is short for "error number", if it's zero, there were no errors)

Something like this should tell you more about the error that happens:

```php
if ($rnum == 0) {
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssiiss", $Wachtwoord, $Achternaam, $Voornaam, $Telnummer, $Telcode, $Username, $Adress);

    $stmt->execute(); // Run the INSERT statement
    if ($stmt->errno) { // Check for errors
        die("Error in inserting: " . $stmt->error); // Print last error
    } else { // No errors
        echo "New record inserted sucessfully"; // Success message
    }
} else {
    echo "Someone already registered using this name";
}
```

I did this only for the `INSERT` statement here, but you should consider doing something like this for the `SELECT` statement too

Comment: Thank you very much! it showed me my error message and I fixed it. I'm doing a group project and my classmate made a mistake in my database. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, I think you probably want to use `&&` instead of `||` in that long `if` at the begining of the PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `echo "New record inserted sucessfully";` line will return even if the query failed, as there is no check to see if the query was actually successful, hence why it's returning that value.

In order to check if there was an error, you need to add `$stmt->error`. There is most likely an error occurring in the Database when trying to insert data. Most likely, from what I can tell,the error is in the `Telnumber` and `Telcode`as they are being treated as integers instead of strings in your prepared statement. Telephone numbers should be treated as strings as you are not performing any kind of math on the numbers, and they can sometimes be formatted to allow things such as dashes, spaces, parentheses, etc.

Comment: I switched them to strings. But it did not fix anything. Also where do I add [$stmt->error] ?